# Numerical operation with absulute value in Django

Tags: django, math, filter, django-templates

I tried to add three different absolute value in my template but I got always 0. I try to explain it:

**My values:**

```
a=-7
b=8
c=10
```

**I tried this method with Django mathfilter:**

```
{{a|abs|add:b|abs|add:c|abs}}
```

I always got 0 because I think the mathfilter can't handle many abs value. Could anyone give me an advice which help me to do this operation? Thnak you in advance!

Comment: I can lookup the `add` filter in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/), but where is `abs`? Is it a custom filter you've made?

Comment: Mathfilter also has `abs` operator. Look at here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's an issue of the `abs` filter. Chaining the `add` filter should make no problems as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10433152/3104974). You Maybe omit the `abs` and see if it works then. Then it's probably the filter.

Otherwise try this workaround:

```
{{ with a2=a|abs }}
    {{ with b2=a2|add:b|abs }}
        {{ with c2=b2|add:c|abs }}
             {# do your stuff with c2 #}
        {{ endwith }}
    {{ endwith }}
{{ endwith }}
```

*Sidenote:* Do you really want to chain the filters? Your result will be `|||a| + b| + c|` which is different from `|a| + |b| + |c|`. For the latter you could do

```
{{ with a2=a|abs b2=b|abs c2=c|abs }}
    {{ a2|add:b2|add:c2 }}
{{ endwith }}
```

Comment: Your answer is working but too complicated to use I think. Despite this this is great work. Although I very sad that we should add 3 number by this way in Django. Eventually I add the three number in QerySet. Thank you!

Comment: Its suggested to this kind of work in your view rather than in template. This is why django template language seems not capable in this kind of situations.